# RHEL 7.5 and Tomcat 8.5 on Azure, not listening on public address

Tags: redhat, azure, tomcat

I have created a RHEL 7.5 hosted on Azure and I have installed Tomcat 8.5 in it.
I have configured Tomcat `server.xml` as following:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
   address="0.0.0.0"
   connectionTimeout="20000"
   redirectPort="8443" />
```

And if I CURL the page locally, it works:

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:8080
```

I have open an `inbound rule` in Azure for any IP to `8080`.
When I do a `netstat -nap` I get this, which I think is Tomcat listening only on IP6 (*I omitted the non interesting records*):

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0    352 10.0.0.4:22             85.195.192.179:58305    ESTABLISHED -
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

I have configured Tomcat to run as a service. Inside `$CATALINA_HOME/bin/` I have created `setenv.sh` using this setting:

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Addresses=true "
```

But or it is not picking up the setting or I am doing something wrong. Any clue?

Comment: What is the problem you are having? You've provided many important details, but the actual problem or error is missing.

Comment: The problem is that if I call Tomcat from outside the server, I get 404. And I resolved by opening RHEL firewall port :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to ensure that port 8080 is open on the Network Security Group (NSG) or set the NSG to none for your VM (not recommended).  NSG docs are here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/nsg-quickstart-portal